# Ruby on rails scraping HTML with nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to scrape the link and title for each listing, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require "net/http"
require "uri"
require "json"
require 'pry'

final_url = 'https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/search/?query=pilgrims+progress'
final_url_uri = URI.parse(final_url)
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(final_url_uri)
response_body = response.body

parse_response = Nokogiri::HTML(response_body)

gberg_array = []

parse_response.css('booklink > .title, .subtitle').map do |a|
    post_title = a.text
    gberg_array.push(post_title)
end

link_array = parse_response.css('li.booklink a').map { |link| link['href'] }

pry.start(binding)
```

Comment: Can you add a description of what you expected and what output your code produced?

Comment: I have rephrased your question and removed a few bits. Do make it a good question, you have to explain what "it doesn't work" means exactly: what happens? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your selector.

```
'booklink > .title, .subtitle'
```

1) `booklink` would look for a tag `<booklink>` I think you want to look for a `li` with the class `booklink` as you did for links:

```
'li.booklink ...'
```

2) Use the selector to find elements with the `title` class:

```
'li.booklink .title'
```

Your technique of getting the text from each `.title` element and inserting it into the array should work. you might want to add `strip` to get rid of trailing new lines.